# List in Hashtable losing all entries

Tags: c#, list, unity-game-engine, hashtable

I am currently trying to implement a sensory system for an AI and have stumbled across a problem I cannot seem to solve myself.

My system has a hashtable containing all information found by its sensors. Each frame it updates each of its sensors like this with the variable "info" being the hashtable:

```
for(int i = 0; i < sensors.Length; i++)
{
    sensors[i].Update(info);
}
```

Each sensor adds a list to the table:

```
public void Update(Hashtable _Info)
{
    List<Transform> detected = new List<Transform>();

    // Run detection code

    _Info.Add(key, detected);
}
```

The key being used is declared in the sensor's class. The problem comes in when I try using the same key for two sensors. I tried accounting for that by checking in the sensor's Update method if the table was containing the key like this:

```
public void Update(Hashtable _Info)
{
    List<Transform> detected = new List<Transform>();
    if(_Info.ContainsKey(key))
        detected = (List<Transform>)_Info[key];

    // Run detection code

    if(!_Info.ContainsKey(key))
        _Info.Add(key, detected);
    else
        _Info[key] = detected;
}
```

I thought this would solve my problem, but it didn't. The first sensor is adding its list of detected transforms to the table correctly. I made sure by checking the table after each individual sensor update. The second sensor however cannot retrieve the list from the table correctly and is working with an empty one, which makes me lose the data of the first sensor. It appears that the table the second sensor receives does contain the correct key, but the list is empty. I checked the table right before the call to the second sensor's Update method and it was still containing the list with the entries of the first sensor but appears to have lost it inside the Update method.

Can someone tell me what is happening here and how I can fix this issue? I need the hashtable to keep all entries, not only the ones of the last sensor it updated.

EDIT:
The key is always a string, sorry for not mentioning that.

Comment: What is the type of `key`?

Comment: What is `key` here? this matters

Comment: The key is always a string, edited the post aswell.

Comment: Do you happen to be running this across multiple threads?

Comment: Can you show a short but complete example of it not working? For example, this is based on the code in the question, and works: http://pastie.org/9272910 (it is sub-optimal, but I didn't want to change much from the code in the question)

Comment: BTW, the only real reason to use `Hashtable` in a scenario like this would be to use the different threading semantics of `Hashtable`. If you aren't using those (which would also require synchronization over the list), you should almost certainly use `Dictionary<string,List<Transform>>` instead - which would be more like: http://pastie.org/9272922

Comment: This is what the scripts look like more complete: http://pastie.org/9272949
While writing this I realized that the line `detected.Clear` might be the culprit here, clearing the list. I feel stupid for not realizing this earlier.
I will modify the code to accomodate this and post again if that fixed it.
I am not using a hashtable because not every sensor might return a List<Transform>.

@James I am not using multi-threading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Mark Gravell I was able to pinpoint and eliminate the problem:

The code I compiled for Mark Gravell to further explain the problem in http://pastie.org/9272949 shows that I have been clearing the `detected` list for every sensor. It appears that cleared the list the first sensor added to the hashtable aswell. I have changed that part as follows:

```
if(_Info.ContainsKey(Key))
    detected = (List<Transform>)_Info[Key];
else
    detected = new List<Transform>();
```

This solved the problem completely. Thanks to everyone responding so quickly and to Mark Gravell who pointed me in the right direction.

Cheers!